# How to create a dicussion forum on android application?

Tags: android, comments, forum

I was thinking of developing a public discussion forum.

The idea is that people can register and login in.

The forum will contain posts on different subjects, and the users can comment, like/dislike. It will be very similar to the Facebook idea of likes and comments.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Currently the question  is too  broad.

Comment: Okay so if that is the case i would clarify a bit. I am looking for something like a comment section in blogs. Where people comment on the above written article. In my case i want to take feedback from people as to how did the application(the one which i have built) helped them and want them to come down and write their experience. The application provides the user legal first aid. So i want the users to write back to us and let us know how did the app help them in getting out of a situation where they had no legal knowledge and the app served its purpose.

Comment: And i want this success story(the users feedback), as we plan to call it, to be visible to everyone using this app and allow the other users to like/dislike the story.